# Why does the ERC20 Token wiki example subtract the balance of address(0) to calculate total supply?

Tags: erc-20

When reading the [ERC20 Token Standard in the Wiki](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard), I've noticed that in its Sample Fixed Supply Token Contract, the value of `balances[address(0)]` is subtracted from the contract's total supply to calculate the total supply.

Here's what `totalSupply()` looks like at the time of writing this question:

```
function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
  return _totalSupply.sub(balances[address(0)]);
}
```

To give more context, `_totalSupply` is created when the contract is instantiated and `.sub()` is a library function from `SafeMath`:

```
contract FixedSupplyToken is ERC20Token {
  using SafeMath for uint;

  mapping(address => uint) balances;
  uint _totalSupply;

  constructor() public {
    decimals = 18;
    _totalSupply = 1000000 * 10**uint(decimals);
    balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
  } 
}
```

**Now there are two things to me that are unclear**:

1. Considering that at the time of creating the contract, only `balances[owner]` should have the value of `_totalSupply`, why are we interested in `balances[address(0)]` in the first place?
2. Assuming that there's zero value in `balances[address(0)]` anyways, why is `totalSupply()` subtracting it every time from `_totalSupply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending tokens to `address(0)` is a means of burning tokens.

When calculating the total supply this way, tokens can be removed from existence without ever having to update the internal `_tokenSupply` field. , which could potentially introduce harmful bugs.

Using ERC-20's `transfer` function, you can send tokens to any address, including `address(0)`. This contract considers transfering tokens to `address(0)` to be the same thing as burning tokens. That's because as the balance of `address(0)` increases, the value returned by the function `totalSupply` decreases. To the outside world then, the tokens that were sent to `address(0)` no longer exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. So `totalSupply()` is supposed to return the total supply (which is already in `_totalSupply`. Can you elaborate on why `balances[address(0)]` is subtracted from it then (to get the total supply we already have even without that subtraction)?

Comment: No one knows the private key for 0x0 (the ethereum address), so sending tokens to it is destroying those tokens (so they no longer count to the total supply).

Comment: What JasoonS said. This way of calculating the `totalSupply` is just to let the outside world know that some tokens are no longer in control of anyone anymore, and therefore, burned.

Comment: I appreciate the responsiveness here! I understand that tokens get burned on address(0). I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm still unsure how one thing relates to the other. Sure sending to that address burns tokens, but we don't send to that address with that code. To me it rather looks like `return totalSupply - [whatever_is_in_balances[address(0)]]`, we don't really touch `address(0)` anywhere else in that contract.

Sorry for being resistant, I hope it makes sense...

Comment: Correct, this function does not transfer tokens. The function `transfer` does, though. And with `transfer`, you can send tokens to any address, including `address(0)`. This contract considers transfering tokens to `address(0)` to be the same thing as burning tokens. That's because as the balance of `address(0)` increases, the value returned by the function `totalSupply` decreases. To the outside world then, the tokens that were sent to `address(0)` no longer exist.

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. So this is really just for "just in case somebody will actually burn tokens by making transfers to `address(0)` in the future, we need to make sure those burned tokens are part of the equation".

This makes sense now. Thank you for being patient everyone!